# oversampling multivariate time series data

Tags: python, classification, time-series, multiclass-classification, oversampling

For some classification needs. I have multivariate time series data composed from 4 stelite images in form of (145521 pixels, 4 dates, 2 bands) I made a classification with tempCNN to classify the data into 5 classes. However there is a big gap between the class 1,2 with 500 samples and 4,5 with 1452485 samples.

I' am wondering if there is a method that help me oversamling the two first classes to make my dataset more adequate for classification.

Comment: Class imbalance almost certainly is not a problem, and there is no need to solve a non-problem. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. According to what you have mentionned class imbalance can be a problem according to its use. In my case I am classifying land use classes. and the gap between the classes samples have given an erroned classification map

Comment: I encourage you to read the material I linked.